# No treatment vs treatment A vs treatment B vs both A and B. Is it ok for "both" to be a category?

Tags: anova, treatment-effect

I want to estimate the effect of some treatments on an outcome. I am interested in the effect of treatment A, the effect of treatment B, and the effect of applying both treatments simultaneously.

I have data on who received which treatment and who received both. Would it be ok to run a regression with:

- An indicator variable for having received only treatment A
- and an indicator variable for having received only treatment B
- and an indicator variable for having received both

Having this "both" category smells like parameter dependency or something to me, so I thought I should ask...

Comment: If the indicators are $0$ or $1$, with $1$ having received the treatment, then the indicator for both will be the product of the indicators for the individual treatments.  Or you

Answer (score -2):

You shouldn't need the indicator variable for having received both, otherwise you're good.

Comment: You need both if allowing for interaction/synergism/non-additivity of the treatments.  Then you can make multiple contrasts.

Comment: @FrankHarrell given your credentials, I believe you, but I don't understand.  Could you point me to somewhere where I can read up on this some more?

Comment: As was said earlier you include a product variable capturing interaction if you don't believe the two treatment effects are additive.